# Return null in Jest test in someComponent

Tags: javascript, react-native, testing, jestjs, enzyme

Im new to testing react-native code using jest and I want to achieve this simple test. I have the following code and I want to test that if `data === '0'` then return value `null`.

```
export class Test extends Component {
...
  _renderRow (data) {
    if (data === '0') {
      return null
    }

    return //other item
  }
...
}
```

I tried the following test, but its still reading the `return //other item` since there is a data variable on it.

```
const _renderRowSpy = jest.spyOn(Feed.prototype, '_renderRow')
  it('should be null', () => {
    function callback(data) {
      expect(data.type()).to.equal(null);
    }
    _renderRowSpy(callback);
  });
```

Comment: Any suggestion how I can write the condition in test, or just read the value inside if statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, got some help from a very good friend. Here's the solution if someone has similar test.

```
it('should be null', () => {
    const instance = wrapper.instance()
    const result = instance._renderRow('0')
    expect(result).toBe(null)
  })
```